# How to create a CMakeLists.txt in order to compile a PNaCl program?

Tags: c++, cmake, google-nativeclient

I have a PNaCl program that I'm trying to compile using CMake.

I included the following lines but doest not work at all:

```
# disable compiler detection
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" Clang)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" Clang)

# specify cross-compilers
set(NACL_BIN /usr/local/share/nacl_sdk/pepper_43/toolchain/mac_pnacl/bin)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${NACL_BIN}/pnacl-clang" CACHE PATH "gcc" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${NACL_BIN}/pnacl-clang++" CACHE PATH "g++" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_AR "${NACL_BIN}/pnacl-ar" CACHE PATH "archive" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_LINKER "${NACL_BIN}/pnacl-clang++" CACHE PATH "linker" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_RANLIB "${NACL_BIN}/pnacl-ranlib" CACHE PATH "ranlib" FORCE)
```

Error printing:
    `pnacl-ld: Unrecognized option: -search_paths_first`

Comment: What is the error printed?

Comment: pnacl-ld: Unrecognized option: -search_paths_first

Comment: But in your snipet there is no setting for pnacl-ld

Comment: This is included in my PATH variable. export PATH="/usr/local/share/nacl_sdk/pepper_43/toolchain/mac_pnacl/bin:${PATH}"

Comment: I can run the pnacl-ld in my command line normally. But, should I set a variable to the file in CMakeLists?

Comment: if think that setting that will be necessary. I've not used pnacl but I have to set every tool that I'm going to use in cmake so that it can create the correct make files.

Comment: It is applying a flag that apparently does not exist in pnacl-ld (-search_paths_first). I will check the settings again.

Comment: I recommend searching for a "CMake PCaCI toolchain" file for you to use or - if they don't work out-of-the-box - as a starting point. First two that came up - without having tested them: [fips](https://github.com/floooh/fips/blob/master/cmake-toolchains/pnacl.toolchain.cmake) and [openzone](https://code.google.com/p/openzone/source/browse/cmake/PNaCl.Toolchain.cmake).

Comment: I tried to use openzone example. Still giving me the same message: pnacl-ld: Unrecognized option: -search_paths_first . I will check fips, thanks!

Comment: The toolchain provided in openzone gave me this  error:pnacl-ld: Unrecognized option: -headerpad_max_install_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Derek's answer:
     `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Generic" CACHE STRING "Target system.")`

Otherwise, CMAKE will use specific flag.

Answer (score 2):

-search_paths_first seems to be an OSX-specific flag, so it seems that CMake isn't aware you are doing a cross build. As far as I know it is not necessary to force the compiler; setting CMAKE_C_COMPILER and the other tools might be sufficient. If there are still issues you might also try setting CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=nacl

Comment: I forced the compiler and it seems that worked but at the end it gave me: pnacl-ld: Unrecognized option: -headerpad_max_install_names

Comment: If I set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=nacl it gives me "System is unknown to cmake"